# Jquery function to validate responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax, user-interface, response

I want a function that validates my responseText. I am not sure of what should be placed in this code.Can someone please help?
`

```
function doThis() {
$ajax(href,{
complete : function(data)
{
var msgElement = document.getElementById("message");
var res= validate(data.responseText);
messageElement.innerHTML = message;
} })}
```

`

The response text is a string of characters "Successfully Completed".
Can anyone please help me what to put in validate() function?

Comment: var res = data.responseText === "Successfully Completed";

Comment: Where do you set `message`?

Comment: The message is actually returned from the function in controller.

Comment: Isn't the controller returning the message in `data.responseText`? What's the difference between that and `message`?

Comment: Message us a div in jsp HTML inside which the data.response text is go be printed.a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validate(message) {
    if (message == "Successfully Completed") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

which can be simplified to:

```
function validate(message) {
    return message == "Successfully Completed";
}
```

If you want a regexp that just checks that the response only contains letters and spaces, you can use:

```
return message.match(/^[a-z\s]+$/i);
```

Comment: Ya this will work well.But as it is using Ajax and JavaScript,will this function protect from security risks?I was trying regex match

Comment: The message  from the controller  changes for different options selected.However in all cases,it consists of a string if letters only. So that is why I was thinking of using regex

Comment: What kind of security risks do you worry about from your controller? Validation is generally only used for user-provided input, not output of your own controller.

Comment: Your sample message is not a string of letters only. It also has a space between the words.